# Label of enumerate as a math environment with number "1" in subscript

Tags: enumerate

I guess an example is the quickest way to understand my problem:
Consider the following enumerate environment using package enumerate

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[$f_1:x\mapsto$]
    \item $x$
    \item $x^2$
    \item $x^3$
    \item $x^4$
    \item $x^5$
    \item $x^6$
    \item $x^7$
    \item $x^8$
    \item $x^9$
    \item $x^{10}$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

And I obtain $f_10$ which is not $f_{10}$.

However if I write

```
  \begin{enumerate}[$f_{1}:x\mapsto$]
    \item $x$
    \item $x^2$
    \end{enumerate}
```

Then the "1" is not recognized as the incremented element. (I have a warning telling me the counter will not be printed, but I am not sure how to change that.)

MWE

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `\bgroup` and `\egroup`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[$f_\bgroup1\egroup:x\mapsto$]
\item $x$
\item $x^2$
\item $x^3$
\item $x^4$
\item $x^5$
\item $x^6$
\item $x^7$
\item $x^8$
\item $x^9$
\item $x^{10}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

You need the [`enumitem` package](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), since it allows more freedom for specifying the appropriate `label` and formatting:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label = {$f_{\arabic*}:x\mapsto{}$}, labelsep = 0pt]
  \item $x$
  \item $x^2$
  \item $x^3$
  \item $x^4$
  \item $x^5$
  \item $x^6$
  \item $x^7$
  \item $x^8$
  \item $x^9$
  \item $x^{10}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the `shortlabels`option of `enumitem`, and two different alignments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc} 

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[$f_\bgroup1\egroup\colon x\mapsto$, labelwidth=\widthof{$f_{99}\colon x\mapsto$}, leftmargin=!, labelsep =0.28em]
\item $x$
\item $x^2$
\item $x^3$
\item $x^4$
\item $x^5$
\item $x^6$
\item $x^7$
\item $x^8$
\item $x^9$
\item $x^{10}$
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{enumerate}[$f_\bgroup1\egroup\colon x\mapsto$, wide=0pt, leftmargin=!, labelsep =0.28em]
\item $x$
\item $x^2$
\item $x^3$
\item $x^4$
\item $x^5$
\item $x^6$
\item $x^7$
\item $x^8$
\item $x^9$
\item $x^{10}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I simply cannot understand why one might want to use the `shortlabels` option in a case like this…